# Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x1f0c63860) to 'NSString' (0x1f0c70290) Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm reading data from the Firebase database which I then sorted in an alphabetical order.
I want to read the keys under the `Scenario` tree, but not the entire data under it.
Then I want to put the keys in the `gradePickerValues1` variable.

Firebase Database Tree

```
    2
      Scenario
       Yeni Senaryo
         OffTime: "12:12"
         OnTime: "12:12"
       Yeni Senaryo2
         OffTime: "12:12"
         OnTime: "12:12"
```

MainActivity

```
  var gradePickerValues1 : [String] = []

  @objc func getSenaryo(){
    let ref = Database
      .database()
      .reference()
      .child(self.chipFieldText.text!)
      .child("Scenario")

    ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
      for group in snapshot.children {
        self.gradePickerValues1.append((group as AnyObject).key)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear... `userSnap.value` is a dictionary (as your variable name also indicates) and you try to (force) cast it to `String`...

Comment: What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
let userDict = userSnap.value as! String
```

do

```
let userDict = userSnap.value as! [String: [String: String]]
```

as your "Scenario" holds a dictionary with a structure of [Name: [Time: String]].

If you want to get "12:12" of `OffTime` of `Yeni Senaryo` from this dictionary, you can do something like this:

```
let value = userDict["Yeni Senaryo"]!["OffTime"]!
```

If the data base structure is more complex, you should use `[String: Any]` instead and use `if let` syntax to perform optional typecast.

EDIT: If you only want to read "Yeni Senaryo" and not the values under, it is simply not possible with Firebase.

See [Best practices for data structure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure):

> Avoid nesting data
>
> Because the Firebase Realtime Database allows nesting data up to 32 levels deep, you might be tempted to think that this should be the default structure. However, when you fetch data at a location in your database, you also retrieve all of its child nodes. In addition, when you grant someone read or write access at a node in your database, you also grant them access to all data under that node. Therefore, in practice, it's best to keep your data structure as flat as possible.

Anyway, if you don't need the nested values and only the names, you can do

```
let userDict = userSnap.value as! [String: Any]
let userNames = Array(userDict.keys)
```

and the array of names as `String`s will be stored in `userNames`.

EDIT2:
Don't typecast `group as AnyObject`.
`AnyObject.key` is not the `key` you want.

```
for group in snapshot.children {
  guard let value = value as? DataSnapshot else { continue }
  self.gradePickerValues1.append(value.key)
}
```

Comment: I don't want to pull the data under the new scenario, I just want to pull the data under scenario.

Comment: What "new scenario" are you talking about? Can you show me an example of the result you want to achieve?

Comment: So I just want to draw the names of the YeniSenaryo and The YeniSenaryo2

Comment: So I don't want to pull the data under YeniSenaryo and YeniSenaryo2

Comment: I updated the code in the topic, but it adds 3 times the data. What's the trouble?

Comment: What is "code in the topic"? Can you elaborate more on it? Also, if it is unrelated to this question, please make a new question, and choose this as an answer if it helped.

Comment: I've updated the code, you can look at the topic. It pulls the data, but adds 3 of the same data.

Comment: <FTransformedEnumerator: 0x281cd78a0> the output I am getting

Comment: Great to hear that it helped!